# import vanilla javascript in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

i am working on a project using Laravel + Vue.
my question is how to import the javascript files to my current component.
basically, i want to convert the HTML code below to a component.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Armenia Map</title>
    <script src="data.js"></script>
    <script src="country.js"></script>

    </head> 
     <body>
      <h1></h1> 
      <div id="map"></div>

      </body>
</html>
```

This is my Compoent:

```js
<template>
    <div id="map"></div>
</template>

<script>
     import * from '../plugins/country';
     import * from '../plugins/map';
    export default {
        mounted(){
        
        }
    }
</script>
```

please if someone can help.
Thank you.

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting any errors with your current code?

Comment: If you add the script tags in index.html, then import statements are not necessary, you can access them via `window.yourVariableFromJsFile`

Comment: thank you for your reply. no error but nothing show

Comment: what do `country.js` contain?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to import, you can also do something like this:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex' 
const Countries = require('../plugins/country')
```

If the file contains javascript code you want to execute emidietely you can do like with bootstrap.js and just require the file.

```
require('./bootstrap')
```